# URI formats are not supported when reading all lines

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, url, file-io

I get the following error :

```
URI formats are not supported.
```

---

```
    string path = @"http://...../xml/en/df.js";
    String[] allLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);
```

Edit :

[image]

Comment: ReadAllLines is for files, try downloading the path instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem :** `System.IO.File` does not support file  downloading from the Internet.

`System.IO.File` only Supports the Path of Local Drives

**Solution:** You should use `WebClient.DownloadFile` for Downloading file from Internet `URL`.

Steps to solve the issue:

1.Use `WebClient.DownloadFile` to Download the File into Local Path.
2.Assign the Downloaded Path to IO.File() to Read the Lines from the file.

**Step1:** Download File.

```
     String source="http://mypath/path2/myfile.js";
     String destination=@"c:\myfile.js";

        void DownloadMyFile()
        {
           using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
           {
               webClient.DownloadFile(source,destination);
           }
        }
```

**Step 2:** Access file from `IO.File` Library

```
String[] allLines =System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(destination);
```

Comment: @just_name: you need to create an object for WebClient webclient=new WebClient(); webclient.DownloadFile(); let me edit answer with complete solution